# How to count the number of times a batch file was run?

Tags: batch-file

I want to count the number of times a batch file was run, is there an easy way I can do this?

I've tried doing with Python, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

for information to "survive", write it to a file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
< "%tmp%\runCount.txt" set /p count=
set /a count+=1
> "%tmp%\runCount.txt" echo %count%
echo this script is running the %count%th time.
```

(Note: this will spit an error message for the very first run ("File not found"))

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: yes, but it will also delete the counter. If needed: `if not exist "%tmp%\runCount.txt" break>"%tmp%\runCount.txt`. `set /a count+=1` will take care of the missing number.